# how to fill textarea in vb6

Tags: html, dom, vb6, webbrowser-control

I am trying to fill a `textarea` in a web page.
First I call

```
site.navigate "www.mysite.com"
```

And here is my code for changing contents of `textarea`:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    site.Document.All.Item("message").Value = "mycontent"
End Sub
```

I also tried either of these:

```
site.Document.All.Item("message").innerhtml = "mycontent"

site.Document.All.Item.form("message").Value = "mycontent"
```

The code doesn't work since it is `textarea`, not `input`.

Comment: Can you also show relevant `HTML`? And what is `site`?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail here? HTML would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that "site" is the standard WebBrowser control. Try using the non-standard property innerText. It works in Micorosft's VB browser control.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    site.Document.All.Item("message").innerText = "mycontent"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple piece of HTML:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM ID="Tart">
            <TEXTAREA ID="Lemon">Lots of text.</TEXTAREA>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And I can quite happily access the textarea called "Lemon" from my browser control <wb> using:

```
wb.Document.All.Item("Lemon").Value = "More Text."
```

... or even ...

```
wb.Document.All.Lemon.Value = "More Text"
```

Maybe you haven't set your element IDs correctly?